# Text Normalizer

Tags: python, performance, natural-language-processing

I am working on a text normalizer. It works just fine with small text files but takes a very long time with large text files such as 5 MB or more.

Is there anything to change in the code to make it run faster on large text files? My guess would be something in the `__preprocess(tmp)` and `__prenormalise(text)`?

````
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
import json
import os
import codecs
import copy
from num2words import num2words
from text_unidecode import unidecode
import argparse

class TextNormaliser:
    def __init__(self, debug=False):
        """
        Args:
            debug (bool, optional): Debug mode
        """
        self.debug = debug
        self.abbreviations = {}
        self.acronyms = {}
        self.currencies = {}

        self.months = [
            'january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july',
            'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december']

        self.number_scale = [
            'thousand', 'thousands', 'million', 'millions',
            'billion', 'billions', 'trillion', 'trillions']

        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        with open(os.path.join(path, 'resources', 'abbreviations.json')) as jf:
            self.abbreviations = json.load(jf)
        with open(os.path.join(path, 'resources', 'acronyms.json')) as jf:
            self.acronyms = json.load(jf)
        with open(os.path.join(path, 'resources', 'currencies.json')) as jf:
            self.currencies = json.load(jf)
        with open(os.path.join(path, 'resources', 'domains.json')) as jf:
            self.domains = json.load(jf)

    def normalise(self, text):
        """Normalise text.

        The function covers numbers, email addresses, ascii characters, etc.

        Args:
            text (str): Input string

        Returns:
            textn (srt): Normalised text
            tokens ([tuples]): List of tuples to track back normalisation

        Examples:
            >>> textn, tokens = tn.normalise("My email is, a@b.com.")
            tokens: (Original, Normalised, Display)
            my email is a at b dot com
            [('My', ['my'], 'My'), ('email', ['email'], 'email'),
            ('is,', ['is'], 'is'),
            ('a@b.com.', ['a', 'at', 'b', 'dot', 'com'], 'a@b.com')]
        """
        return self.__normalise(text)

    def normalise_file(self, path):
        """Normalise text from a file.

        The function covers numbers, email addresses, ascii characters, etc.

        Args:
            path (str): Path to a file

        Returns:
            textn (srt): Normalised text, or None if file does not exists
            tokens ([tuples]): List of tuples to track back normalisation,
                or None if file doesnot exists

        Raises:
            Exception: If file cannot be read

        Examples:
            >>> textn = tn.normalise_file('./trans.txt')
        """
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                with codecs.open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
                        return self.__normalise(f.readline())
            else:
                return None, None
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception('ERR Normalise_file: {}'.format(e))

    def __normalise(self, text):
        text = self.__prenormalise(text)
        tmp = []
        for idx, t in enumerate(text.split()):
            tmp.append((t, idx))
        original = copy.deepcopy(tmp)

        # Preprocessing
        tokens = self.__preprocess(tmp)
        
        # Convert to result format
        ret_text, ret_tokens = self.__generate_results(original, tokens)
        return ret_text, ret_tokens

    def __prenormalise(self, text):
        text = text.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
        text = re.sub(r'\b\?\b', ' ', text)
        text = re.sub(r'\b\!\b', ' ', text)
        text = re.sub(r'\b\"\b', ' ', text)
        text = re.sub(r'\b\--\b', ' ', text)

        chars = list(text)
        for i, c in enumerate(chars):
            if i < 1 or i > len(chars)-1:
                continue
            if c == ',':
                if not(chars[i-1].isnumeric() and
                   chars[i-1].isnumeric()):
                    chars[i] = ', '
            text = ''.join(chars)
        return text

    def __preprocess(self, tokens):
        # Remove spaces and some special encoding
        for idx, t in enumerate(tokens):
            i = t[1]
            t = t[0]
            t = t.replace('&amp;', '&')

            hints = ['[Music]', '[Laughter]', '[Applause]']
            for hint in hints:
                t = t.replace(hint, '')

            del tokens[idx]
            tokens.insert(idx, (t.strip(), i))

        # Remove last dot
        if len(tokens):
            if tokens[-1][0].endswith('.'):
                i = tokens[-1][1]
                t = tokens[-1][0]
                del tokens[-1]
                tokens.append((t[:-1], i))

        return tokens
    
   
    def __rstrip(self, token):
        for i in range(5):
            if len(token):
                if token[-1] in [',', '.', ';', '!', '?', ':', '"']:
                    token = token[:-1]
                else:
                    break
        return token

    def __lstrip(self, token):
        for i in range(5):
            if len(token):
                if token[0] in [',', '.', ';', '!', '?', ':', '"', '\'']:
                    token = token[1:]
                else:
                    break
        return token


    def __generate_results(self, original, normalised):
        words = []
        for t in normalised:
            if len(t[0]):
                words.append(t[0])
        text = ' '.join(words)

        tokens = []
        if len(original):
            for t in original:
                idx = t[1]
                words = []
                for t2 in normalised:
                    if idx == t2[1]:
                        words.append(t2[0])
                display_text = self.__rstrip(t[0])
                display_text = self.__lstrip(display_text)
                tokens.append((t[0], words, display_text))
        else:
            tokens.append(('', '', ''))

        return text, tokens   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--textfile', type=str, required=True, help='input directory or file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    tn = TextNormaliser(False)
    with open(args.textfile) as fd:
        lines = fd.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            normalised, tokens = tn.normalise(line)
            print(normalised)
```
````

Comment: To reinforce a suggestion you've already received, when your code is too slow, don't waste a lot of time deeply studying code to determine what needs optimization. Instead, just measure it -- for example, with `timeit`. It will usually save you a lot of effort, because you'll focus more quickly on the trouble spots. Of course, sometimes once you find the trouble, you'll realize there's no way to fix it without a bigger rewrite of your strategy and code -- but that's only a potential concern, after you have some hard evidence.

Comment: Please do not change the code in your question after receiving answers. Doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest to do some profiling, or simply using `timeit` for measuring which part of code takes the long time, and then focus on that:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()
text = self.__prenormalise(text) # for example
end = timer()
print('__prenormalise took', end - start) # time in seconds
```

I'm suspicious about the `__prenormalise` method. You're doing there several simple replacements, which can be merged into a single one instead:

```
text = re.sub(r"\b(\?|\!|\"|--|\n)\b", " ", text)
```

even better you should use [re.compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) to compile the pattern once anywhere outside the function, so it is complied only once. If you would put this into a function, it would get compiled every time the function is executed:

```
# replace all diacritics in a single go
RE_DIACRITICS = re.compile(r"\b(\?|\!|\"|--|\n)\b")
```

then in the function you can use that compiled regex:

```
# use inside your methods like this
text = RE_DIACRITICS.sub(" ", text)
```

however the slowest part is probably the loop, where you iterate through the whole text one character at a time:

```
for i, c in enumerate(chars):
    if i < 1 or i > len(chars)-1:
        continue
    if c == ',':
        if not(chars[i-1].isnumeric() and
           chars[i-1].isnumeric()):
            chars[i] = ', '
    text = ''.join(chars)
```

The condition `if i < 1 or i > len(chars)-1` is executed every time but it matters only during the first and last iteration. So you can throw it away and iterate only through a slice starting at the 2nd character and ending at the last-but-one:

```
for i, c in enumerate(chars[1:-1]):
```

However that is still slow. The thing what you want to do is to replace a comma between two non-numbers with the same thing except putting a space there, right? That could be done with a straightforward regex substitution instead of going one character after another manually. So the whole loop `for i, c in enumerate(chars):` can be replaced with this regex:

```
 # replace comma between non-numbers with comma + space
 text = re.sub("(?<!\d)(,)(?!\d)", "\g<1> ", text)
```

This regex is using negative lookahead and negative lookbehind, which you can find in the [re module documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). It looks for a comma which is not following nor followed by a number, and then it replaces the comma with first matched group (which is the comma itself) plus space. For working with regexes I recommend using regex101.com, which can visualise results in real time. Here's the regex from above https://regex101.com/r/tccMoA/1

Comment: thanks for you answer i did everything you said but im having trouble understanding where to put the re.compile and the re.finditer. Is there a way  to contact you privately? Much appreciated.

Comment: I updated my answer further

Comment: @ yedpodtrzitko I tried the timeit you told me about its very usefull and i discovered that the __generate_results and the __preprocess are also taking alot of time im not sure why. I hope you can help with that? The changes you did to the __prenormalize were excellent now its much faster!

Answer (score 1):

#### `__preprocess()`

`token` is a list of (test, index) tuples.  So, it looks like `idx` and `i` will always be the same value. `enumerate` is not needed, just use `i`.

```
    # Remove spaces and some special encoding
    for t, i in tokens:
        t = t.replace('&amp;', '&')

        hints = ['[Music]', '[Laughter]', '[Applause]']
        for hint in hints:
            t = t.replace(hint, '')
```

`tokens` is a list.  Don't delete and then insert a new value, just replace the value.  Also, `i` and `t` aren't used when removing the last dot.

```
        tokens[idx] = (t.strip(), i)

    if len(tokens) and tokens[-1][0].endswith('.'):
       tokens[-1] = (t[:-1], i)

    return tokens
```

#### `__rstrip()` and  `__lstrip()`

The Python str type has methods for `__rstrip()` and `__lstrip()`.  Triple quotes can be used to enclose a string containing both kinds of single quotes.

```
def __rstrip(self, token):
    return token.rstrip(''',.;!?:'"''')

def __lstrip(self, token):
    return token.lstrip(''',.;!?:'"''')
```

#### `__generate_results()`

The `for t in normalised:` loop can be a generator expression:

```
text = ' '.join(w for w, _ in normalised if w)
```

It looks like the `for t in original` loop could be replaced by `itertools.groupby()` and grouping by the index in `normalized`.

The way you are using `__rstrip()` and `__lstrip()`, just use the `strip()` method; it strips from both ends of the string.

```
from itertools import groupby

tokens = []
for idx, group in groupby(normalized, key=lambda t:t[1]):
    words = [w for w, _ in group]
    display_text = original[idx][0].strip(''',.;!?:'"''')

    tokens.append((original[idx], words, display_text))
```

#### main code

An open file is already an iterable, so you don't need to read it all in and then iterate over it.

```
with open(args.textfile) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        ...
```